# Split a string after a specific character in BigQuery

Tags: split, google-bigquery

I have a field that contains street name, state, and zip code that I need to pull just the state abbreviation from. I tried using SUBSTR but the challenge is that sometimes the zip codes are the full 9 digit zipcodes (and not just the 5 digit zips). I'm sure there is an easy way to do this with maybe REGEX but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

**Example**:
123 Street ABC, NY 12345
1234 Street, NY 12345-1234

**Need to return**:  NY

Answer (score 0):

Below works backward and looks for first 2 chars, so it does not matter how zip cod is represented or if it missed at all

```
select reverse(regexp_extract(reverse(address), r'[A-Z]{2}')) state
from `project.datatset.table`
```